# SystemOutOfMemoryException was thrown frequently, even though the used memory never go pass 60%

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, virtual-machine, out-of-memory

I hosted all the web that I've created for the company on an Virtual Machine's IIS. I set that VM to have 8 GB of RAM. On the recent day, I noticed that I got couple SystemOutOfMemory Exception a day, even though my RAM usage, as indicate in Resource Monitor, never go pass 60% mark.

My VM is 64 bit and I compiled my code with "AnyCPU" option.

Comment: Are you sure if it is real OOM, an not something like allocating too big arrays (`new double[int.MaxValue]`)?

Comment: If memory on the managed heap is fragmented you can easily get OOM when below capacity. Do you have a lot of pinned objects? Are you allocating large objects?

Comment: I use ASP.NET cache to store big DataTable object (about 4-5k rows with 10-15 columns). I set the Expired Time to be 10 min.

Comment: @mikez assuming OP runs site in IIS in x64 process getting into memory fragmentation is very unlikely.

Comment: I don't think increase memory from 8 GB to 16 GB will help in this case?